# SDWebImage with local png

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

I wanted to use sdwebimage to cache image from my local album in my app written in Objective-c. Does anyone knows whether the feature has been implemented in sdwebimage and also whether someone used this in their app?

Answer (score 0):

I needed exactly this feature.
It's seems there is no support for local image with SDWebImage library.

Check this thread :
https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/697

Answer (score -1):

From [SDWebImage Github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

SDWebImage provide a `UIImageView` category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework.

So as per the above statement then answer to your question is **YES**, SDWebImage provides feature of caching & implementing it is very simple all things are provided in the mentioned link of SDWebImage.

Comment: Yea, I am aware that SDWebImage is able to cache web images, however instead of providing URL of the image (which I am using now), I wanted to provide the asset image to SDWebImage.

Comment: @Calvin provide asset image to SDWebImage sounds like providing image Name store locally or you have image in NSData format please clarify ?

Comment: I wanted to provide an image name stored locally on the disk in an album.

Comment: This does not answer is question : how to add local image to SDWebImage. It's not the same as caching.